# Is it possible to bring these chip temperatures down?

Tags: power-management, overheating, temperature, devices

Today I installed kubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, and I'm having some problems with it. One of the problems is the high temperature of two chips. When running the command `sensors` in the terminal I get the following output (at idle):

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +60.0°C  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +60.0°C
```

The last two devices have a 60.0°C temperature, and it seems the chips are located under the keyboard to the left because that region feels really hot and makes it annoying to type or to place my hands above the keyboard. Is it possible to bring these temperatures down?

I'm already using tlp, and thermald came preinstalled in the system.

EDIT: The laptop is a [Gigabyte Sabre 17](https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/Sabre-17#kf) with an i7-7700HQ processor. Here are its details using Speccy on my Windows 10 partition:
[image]

Comment: Without giving details about the laptop or the type of chips, it will be difficult to give any advice.

Comment: Try fabledpigs last entry here - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1725560#p1725560.

Answer (score 0):

`sensors` reads information from the kernel and sometimes it seems a bit off. To confirm you do have a problem read the information directly from the kernel yourself with this command:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t
INT3400 Thermal  20000
SEN1             54000
SEN2             51000
SEN3             58000
SEN4             61000
pch_skylake      -44500
B0D4             49000
x86_pkg_temp     51000
```

There are three implied decimal places so the actual temperature of `X86_pkg_temp` is 51.000 Celsius. As you can tell from the `pch_skylake` sensor a temperature of `-44.5` is out to lunch. I've noticed this one sensor is often out of wack.

**Hint:** Copy and paste the terminal command after the `$` sign into your terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of laboriously typing it in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though this method is giving the same readings as `sensors` in my case. And I don't know why is it a sky-lake sensor in a kaby-lake chip.

Comment: Your temperatures aren't really that hot. You might bring them down about 10 degrees if you have a nVidia graphics card and disable it to use Intel built in GPU instead. If your BIOS can force fans on all the time it will also bring temps down at the expense of more noise and shorter battery life. As far as Kaby Lake is concerned, that portion of the chip is based on Sky Lake technology I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately my Nvidia card causes a lot of screen tearing in the Plasma desktop and it goes really hot even if I use it with `optirun` for a very lightweight game, so I'm only using the Intel gpu already.

Comment: I had problems with the nVidia 390 drivers in 18.04 so I used the 384 drivers instead. You might want  to try that later.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix there are other reports of over-temp with this PCH, etc., including a report of a fix by using alternate driver for wifi as I linked above.